# Sage: same code, (vastly) different results locally and at aleph.sagemath.org

Tags: sage

I have SageMath 9.4 for Ubuntu 20.04 downloaded from [a french mirror](http://www-ftp.lip6.fr/pub/math/sagemath/linux/64bit/sage-9.4-Ubuntu_20.04-x86_64.tar.bz2) and I am trying to run an [LWE estimator](https://bitbucket.org/malb/lwe-estimator) by [Albrecht et al](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/jmc-2015-0016/html).

#### Running on Aleph

Without any problem, I can paste [the estimator.py code](https://bitbucket.org/malb/lwe-estimator/src/master/estimator.py) into [Aleph](http://aleph.sagemath.org/), followed by my parameters, e.g.:

```
n, stdv = 1024, 2^-30.0
set_verbose(1)
_ = estimate_lwe(n, sqrt(2*pi)*stdv, 2^32,  reduction_cost_model=BKZ.sieve, secret_distribution=(0,1))
```

from which I obtain

```
Warning: the LWE secret is assumed to have Hamming weight 512.
usvp: rop: â‰ˆ2^108.0,  red: â‰ˆ2^108.0,  Î´_0: 1.005242,  Î²:  266,  d: 1889,  m:      864,  repeat:        1,  k:        0,  postprocess:        0
 dec: rop: â‰ˆ2^131.5,  m:     1198,  red: â‰ˆ2^131.5,  Î´_0: 1.004529,  Î²:  332,  d: 2222,  babai: â‰ˆ2^117.5,  babai_op: â‰ˆ2^132.6,  repeat:       17,  Îµ: 0.250000
dual: rop: â‰ˆ2^112.1,  m:      994,  red: â‰ˆ2^112.1,  Î´_0: 1.005070,  Î²:  280,  repeat: â‰ˆ2^60.8,  d: 1986,  c:        8,  k:       32,  postprocess:        1
```

which tells me that I have 108.0 bits of security (2nd line: `usvp: rop: â‰ˆ2^108.0`). Until here -- fine.

#### Running locally

Now I need to process a heap of parameters automatically, which I am trying to run locally (using the aforementioned version of SageMath). Problems arise (with 1-3 possibly irrelevant, 4 indeed relevant):

1. With the very same code I get: `ImportError: cannot import name complex_mpfr`, which seems to be resolved by adding `import sage.all` in the very beginning.
2. Then I get: `n, stdv = 1024, 2^-30.0 .. TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'int' and 'float'` which I fix by replacing `2^-30.0` with `9.3132257e-10`.
3. Next run: `NameError: name 'set_verbose' is not defined` which I solved by importing `from sage.misc.verbose import verbose, set_verbose, get_verbose` (still some warnings -- deprecated stuff and syntax -- which I ignore)
4. Final run: I get the results,

but with completely different numbers:

```
Warning: the LWE secret is assumed to have Hamming weight 512.
usvp: rop: â‰ˆ2^44.9,  red: â‰ˆ2^44.9,  Î´_0: 1.013310,  Î²:   40,  d: 1024,  m:       -1,  repeat:        1,  k:        0,  postprocess:        0
 dec: rop: â‰ˆ2^43.6,  m:     -614,  red: â‰ˆ2^43.6,  Î´_0: 1.021759,  Î²:   40,  d:  410,  babai:        1,  babai_op: â‰ˆ2^15.1,  repeat:        1,  Îµ:        1
```

(and then `TypeError: unable to convert '2.5275472536193645856387667200778292581e-30+2.6845375638424411831060264943943048062e9*I' to a real number` which I ignore)

Compared to 108.0 from Aleph, my local result 44.9 is completely false, though running the same code. I also pasted the modified code into Aleph and it still gives 108.0.

Find [my final code at Pastebin](https://pastebin.pl/view/ce3f0579) (gives results both on Aleph and locally).

Comment: answered at https://ask.sagemath.org/question/61038/same-code-vastly-different-results-locally-and-at-alephsagemathorg/?answer=61049